# Problems installing Multicore-TSNE

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

I'm currently attempting to install [Multicore-TSNE](https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/Multicore-TSNE) and have to use Windows for that. I'm using Python 3.6.

After running `pip install .` (as explained in the installation instructions) in the correct folder, I always end up with the following error:

```
> C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\pathToMultiCoretSNE\multiCoretSNE\Multicore-TSNE-master>C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe
> install . Processing
> c:\users\myuser\desktop\pathToMultiCoretSNE\multicoretsne\multicore-tsne-master
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in
> c:\users\myuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packa ges (from MulticoreTSNE==0.1)
> (1.14.3) Requirement already satisfied: cffi in
> c:\users\myuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packag es (from MulticoreTSNE==0.1)
> (1.11.5) Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in
> c:\users\myuser\anaconda3\lib\site-p ackages (from
> cffi->MulticoreTSNE==0.1) (2.18) Building wheels for collected
> packages: MulticoreTSNE   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for
> MulticoreTSNE ... error   Complete output from command
> C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "impor t setuptools,
> tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-re
> q-build-zcvir1og\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
> open)(__file__);code=f.r ead().replace('\r\n',
> '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdi st_wheel -d
> C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-hisywqoj --python-tag c
> p36:   running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py  
> creating build   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6   creating
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MulticoreTSNE   copying
> MulticoreTSNE\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MulticoreTSNE  
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MulticoreTSNE\tests   copying
> MulticoreTSNE\tests\test_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MulticoreT
> SNE\tests   copying MulticoreTSNE\tests\__init__.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MulticoreTS NE\tests   running egg_info  
> creating MulticoreTSNE.egg-info   writing
> MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\PKG-INFO   writing dependency_links to
> MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\dependency_links.txt   writing requirements to
> MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\requires.txt   writing top-level names to
> MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\top_level.txt   writing manifest file
> 'MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'   reading manifest file
> 'MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'   reading manifest template
> 'MANIFEST.in'   writing manifest file
> 'MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'   running build_ext   cmake
> version 3.11.3
> 
>   CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
> error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the specified file
> 
>   ----------------------------------------   Failed building wheel for
> MulticoreTSNE   Running setup.py clean for MulticoreTSNE Failed to
> build MulticoreTSNE Installing collected packages: MulticoreTSNE  
> Running setup.py install for MulticoreTSNE ... error
>     Complete output from command C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "imp ort setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-
> req-build-zcvir1og\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
> open)(__file__);code=f .read().replace('\r\n',
> '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" i nstall
> --record C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-688ufu7j\install-r
> ecord.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>     running install
>     running build
>     running build_py
>     creating build
>     creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
>     creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MulticoreTSNE
>     copying MulticoreTSNE\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MulticoreTSNE
>     creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MulticoreTSNE\tests
>     copying MulticoreTSNE\tests\test_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Multicor eTSNE\tests
>     copying MulticoreTSNE\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Multicore TSNE\tests
>     running egg_info
>     writing MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\PKG-INFO
>     writing dependency_links to MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
>     writing requirements to MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\requires.txt
>     writing top-level names to MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\top_level.txt
>     reading manifest file 'MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>     reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
>     writing manifest file 'MulticoreTSNE.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>     running build_ext
>     cmake version 3.11.3
> 
>     CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
>     error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the specified file
> 
>     ---------------------------------------- Command "C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize
> ;__file__='C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-zcvir1og\\setu
> p.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
> open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
> '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
> --record C:\Users \myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-688ufu7j\install-record.txt
> --single-versi on-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\myuser\App Data\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-zcvir1og\
> 
> C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\pathToMultiCoretSNE\multiCoretSNE\Multicore-TSNE-master>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is there any additional information I could provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this by simply using the [pip package](https://pypi.org/project/MulticoreTSNE/).